# Keyboard vs mouse power consumption

Tags: power

I have a wireless keyboard (logitech pro 2000) and I have not changed its batteries (2 AA) for about 6 months, not even once! On the other hand, I have a wireless mouse (logitech performance mouse mx) and by golly I have to change its battery (1 AA) every 1-1½ week!
One could say that I use the mouse a bit more often but what is with its excessive power consumption? Is it just bad design? (also had had another logitech mouse, same deal) or is it normal that a mouse consumes this much more power because it has to track & send the point coordinates in every milliseconds?

Comment: perhaps a question for superuser.com?

Comment: @kenny No, it is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Off the top of my head I would think the keyboard would last longer.   First you probably use it less than you do the mouse.   Then it's usage pattern is basically:  sleep and wait for a key to be pressed.  So he spends a lot of time sleeping in a very lower power state doing nothing.  It's easy to wake up to a key press, you just sit there an wait for an interrupt to come in.

The mouse on the other hand needs to know when you move it.  He uses an LED that's being shone down onto your desk to detect movement.  Glowing that LED takes power.  So the whole time that it's detecting movement it's pumping power into this LED.

Now a quick check of a colleagues mouse here showed that when it was idle it goes into a blinking state probably to conserve power.  I swear I've seen an old logitech that was left in a box blinking away too.

While it could eventually either go into a really slow blink, or alternatively have some other way of waking up like an accelerometer (although that's unlikely due to cost).  The fact that it has to sit there and blink in idle instead of going to sleep right away tells me it will draw more power.

That's my best guess without thinking about it too hard.

Answer (score 6):

There are three primary sources of power draw in these devices: the "sensor", the microcontroller, and the radio.  To conserve power, everything in the device is put in a low power state (sleep) and kept there for as long as possible.

For the keyboard, the "sensor" is a keypress, which will wake up the microcontroller and the radio in order to transmit that keypress.  After a short timeout (to capture another keypress in quick succession, if present), everything goes to sleep.  This is a very efficient strategy.

By comparison, the mouse can only tell if it's moving by the use of a sensor - either an accelerometer or the sensing LED+optics themselves.  Most battery-powered mice will enter a low power mode whereby the position is sensed less frequently, then switch to full power mode when motion is detected in order to properly resolve fine motion.  They do this in an attempt to preserve battery life because powering the LED and the CMOS sensor in the mouse take a non-trivial amount of power.  This is why most wireless mice have off switches and wireless keyboards do not - the mouse needs to actively check to see if it needs to wake up.

When the mouse is being moved, the microcontroller and radio are both active. From some quick research, mice typically broadcast movement at between 50 and 100Hz, so the packet rate handled by the microcontroller and radio is an order of magnitude higher than what is required for the keyboard (1 packet per keypress).

Finally, in your specific case, your mouse only has half the total energy storage capacity as the keyboard (one AA battery vs. two in the keyboard), so even if everything else were identical, the battery would still last only half as long.

Comment: Hah +1 for the battery difference I didn't even read that :)

Comment: My Logitech mouse (model M505) uses two AA batteries (and they typically last a couple of months or more).